# JPQL combine IN with LIKE

Tags: list, jpql

is there a possibility in a JPQL query to use a `LIKE` on a List (as with the `IN` keyword).

Something like: `"Select a From Table a WHERE a.field LIKE IN :list"`

So that i can set the Parameters like this: `{"12%","13%","16%"}`
or do i have to chain dynamicly many OR-clauses?

THX,
Necros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not possible the way you like, but you could use several OR'ed conditions like `Select * from table1 where x like "12%1234" OR x like "23%"`.

If that doesn't work because the list is too long or whatever, maybe look at the criteria api to programmatically OR the conditions you need?